# How to avoid making the app crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I recently started making a new app, which basically is a `ListView` with clickable items, and I set it to open another app. The problem is, if an app doesn't exist, the app crashes. Here's an example:

```
if(position == 0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
    i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.example");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Suppose that package name doesn't exist. What should I add to make it send you a message saying the app doesn't exist and avoid crashing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catch?

```
if(position == 0) {
    try
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        PackageManager managerclock = getPackageManager();
        i = managerclock.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.example");
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Do what ever you want
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple try catch may be? Another thing you could do is by querying the OS whether an app of that name exists or not. Start only if the app exists !

```
     public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
        pm = getPackageManager();        
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

This tutorial might be help as well:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/28/how-to-check-whether-an-application-is-installed-in-your-android-phone-2/

Answer (score 1):

First check if the package is installed like this..

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
}
```